# Similar questions pane travels through bottom footer

Tags: bug, design

When typing a question and "similar questions" appears, it travels *over* the bottom footer (from Software Engineering):

[image]

On MSE a similar problem exists with the "How to Format" toolbar, though it appears the transparency is different for the background:

[image]

It seems this should not do this at all as it's pretty ugly appearance wise. And rather Clippy like, to be honest.

Using Chrome, with a resolution of 1080x960.

Comment: If that's intended behavior it would be good for network wide transparency settings to avoid the... hideous look that SESE has.

Comment: You should post the SESE one on the meta there because that's a site-specific design issue; the sidebar covers the footer everywhere else from what I can see (i.e. the handful I just checked).. but sure I agree with you